Code containing conditionals (if, else) not working in Rstudio
I'm trying to learn R using CS50R, currently watching the third lecture on applying functions. This is the function created in the lecture.
get_votes <- function(candidate = "Votes"){
  votes <- suppressWarnings(as.integer(readline(candidate))) 
}

mario <- get_votes("Mario: ")
peach <- get_votes("Peach: ")
bowser <- get_votes("Bowser: ")

total_votes <- sum(mario, peach, bowser)
cat("Total votes:", total_votes)

I'm trying to write code for what should happen if the total_votes variable is not an integer.
I've written the following code on line 12 (after all the code previously written)
if(!is.na(total_votes)){
  cat("Total votes:", total_votes)
} else {
  return(paste0("Invalid ", "answer"))
}


But this is not working, and the I get nothing after I enter a non-numerical input for one of the three candidates.
In the lecture, however, the following has been done:
get_votes <- function(candidate = "Votes"){
  votes <- suppressWarnings(as.integer(readline(candidate))) 
  if(is.na(votes)) {
    return(0)
  }
  else{
    return(votes)
  }
}

mario <- get_votes("Mario: ")
peach <- get_votes("Peach: ")
bowser <- get_votes("Bowser: ")

total_votes <- sum(mario, peach, bowser)

cat("Total votes:", total_votes)


What is the difference between what I have tried to do and what has been done in the lecture, and why is my code not working?

I'm bit sceptical regarding "get nothing" part, but behaviour can be different depending on how you are executing that code. In interactive session, at least with R 4.4.1, you should actually be treated with the following error:
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level

This is also pretty good hint on what's off, return() is part of a function definition, but in your case there is no function to return from.
In other words, drop that return() :
total_votes <- sum(1, 2, NA)
if(!is.na(total_votes)){
  cat("Total votes: ", total_votes)
} else {
  message("Invalid answer")
}
#> Invalid answer


Thank you! That really helped. I'm following the lectures, and there wasn't this clarification made that return can only be used for functions, and I didn't know about message(). Is there some material I could use to learn more about the syntax and "grammar" for the lack of a better word, used in writing codes properly. I'm learning programming for the first time. Would appreciate any direction, thanks!

Make a habit of using R help & Vignettes as a primary source of information, i.e. use ?return to get help on that; or in RStudio, just move cursor to any keyword or function and press F1. And check  Help > R Help in RStudio (or help.start() for base help), it's well worth browsing through that collection so you'd know what's there. If the pace and style of CS50R suits you, it makes sense to stick with it for now, not getting every little detail is kind of norm when starting out and you'll keep discovering new approaches, functions and packages for years (or decades, if you choose to).
